# '95 Nissan Hardbody, auto trannie slipping in 1st, was told *not* to flush/replace the ATF?

Tags: automatic-transmission, nissan, transmission-fluid

Of the 5 people I've asked IRL, two have told me something like "in older trucks sometimes the transmission fluid is almost 'holding together' a bad transmission, and doing a flush & replacement could cause premature failure"  I thought it odd but one of the two people was a friend who's a mechanic (at a very low-level local garage but still)  Want to do anything I can to keep this on the road, while I figure out & save for a transmission rebuild/replacement (still unsure which is best here)

I bought this truck earlier this month, was all I could afford, long story short it drove fine with me and when my mechanic drove me in it, then my neighbor backs it out of the driveway, shifts from R to D quickly and gasses it and it slips 100% (thing shifts real slow....)  From then-on it's been a nightmare in 1st, once I get to 12-15mph and it switches to 2nd it's been fine (except *one* incident where it kept bucking back&forth slipping/catching, was the furthest I'd driven it and haven't driven half that far since)

I've got one of the mechanic's friends saying he has a siphoning-pump at his place and he's advising me to come by, I had some "Lucas anti-slip" and he told me to get another bottle and that we'd siphon-out that much, then replace w/ the anti-slip...I'm hesitant so was hoping to run this by an audience before doing this!!  (will likely get a tube and do it myself, want to be more precise w/ the fluid-level than I'm expecting he'll be)

Thanks a TON for any help on this one!!  Oh and one thing I should note that I've found weird is that I've had it for ~3wks now, and the thing had a very slow ATF leak when I got it, but after 2wks the dipstick was still reading over-full by a little bit (I tried every conceivable way of measuring, car cold/hot, in/out of all the gears, etc and it always reads past the Hot marking no matter what)  Because I can literally see a tiny (dime-sized) droplet on the ground under the ATF tank 2/3 morning, I've been adding a little of that anti-slip to replace what I expect it's lost, but am at a loss for why it still seems over-full if it's been leaking for almost 3wks now...mechanic friend looked at this and said it's fine, didn't give a rational answer as to how it's OK to have the fluid clearly above the dipstick's Hot top-line...glad the internet exists, thanks again!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/17217/4152

Comment: I think the main issue is that new fluid will have new detergents, which may cause or exacerbate leaks.  In your case, I would avoid new fluid with increased lubricity - that can't help your slipping.  Get it fixed - the transmission may not be ruined yet.  Try starting in direct 2 "L2" or whatever it's labeled, and then once moving, shift into drive.  But I wouldn't be driving it much at all - you don't want a disk or plate coming apart.

Comment: Why let the neighbor drive it? When things go wrong they ALWAYS deny being the cause...

Comment: Thanks for the link Paulstser2 will go check that out!

Comment: @SolarMike I was weak-willed and dumb, it was a mistake I regret doing, I didn't even bother to confront him over it because it's futile but yeah lesson learned!!!!  Oddly enough, the trannie is catching onto 2nd gear WAY easier now....only thing done was a partial ATF swap of like 1.5qt of lucas anti-slip for ~1.2qt of the old, in-car ATF (so a rejuvenation of the ATF *as well as* bringing it down to the proper level)

Comment: @SteveRacer after a lot of looking into this I think that that's precisely what it is IE that the detergents can "compromise" solids in the ATF that your clutch packs may be depending on to grip although in such cases the AT is basically shot anyways and you're just speeding-up demise by swapping...my ATF has looked&smelled good since day1, thankfully, which has been reassuring- it's also taking me ~5 or less tries to get it to catch 2nd gear so I can leave my street, used to be 10+ tries, only difference is slight reduction in ATF level (to proper level) and a ~1.3qt ATF swap to Lucas!